# How to find out in advance the address of the smart contract I am going to deploy?

Tags: solidity, rsk

I have a Solidity smart contract `ContractFactory` which I am deploying on [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/) and developing in [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started). `ContractFactory` has a `deploy` function which produces new `Child` smart contracts.
​

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
​
contract ContractFactory {
    event ContractDeployed(address owner, address childContract);
​
    function deploy() public {
        Child newContract = new Child(msg.sender);
        emit ContractDeployed(msg.sender, address(newContract));
    }
}
​
contract Child {
    address owner;
​
    constructor(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
    }
}
```

Can I know before invoking the `deploy` function what address on [RSK](https://explorer.rsk.co/)  will a new `Child` smart contract receive?

Answer (score 15):

You can go even further and make use of the deterministic deployment technique which exploits [CREATE2](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014) specification. Here the address of the future smart contract is a `keccak256` hash of the 4 parameters:

1. `0xFF`, a constant that prevents collisions with CREATE
2. the sender’s own address
3. salt (an arbitrary 32 bytes long value provided by the sender)
4. `keccak256` of the to-be-deployed contract’s bytecode

Notice that with `CREATE2` you can not only predict the deployed smart contract address, but you can actually influence what this address will be by changing the `salt` value.

Try adding the following function to your `ContractFactory`

```
function deployCreate2(bytes32 _salt) public {
    Child newContract = new Child{salt: _salt}(msg.sender);
    emit ContractDeployed(msg.sender, address(newContract));
}
```

With this test you can determine the deployed smart contract address.

```js
it('Should determine the Child address', async () => {
    const Child = await ethers.getContractFactory('Child');
    const { data: initCode } = Child.getDeployTransaction(deployer.address);
    const initCodeHash = ethers.utils.keccak256(initCode);
    const salt = ethers.utils.keccak256(0x0);
    const childAddress = ethers.utils.getCreate2Address(
      factory.address,
      salt,
      initCodeHash,
    );
    const deployTx = factory.deployCreate2(salt);
    await expect(deployTx)
      .to.emit(factory, 'ContractDeployed')
      .withArgs(deployer.address, childAddress);
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes you can. The deployed smart contract address is a function (`keccak256` hash) of 2 parameters:

1. the deployer address (EAO or another smart contract)
2. the `nonce` which is a transaction count for the deployer address
   You can use Ethers.js `getTransactionCount` function to find the nonce, and `getContractAddress` function to calculate the future smart contract address.

Use this test to predict the `Child` address:

```js
it('Should predict Child address', async () => {
    const nonce = await ethers.provider.getTransactionCount(factory.address);
    const anticipatedAddress = ethers.utils.getContractAddress({
      from: factory.address,
      nonce,
    });
    const tx = await factory.deploy();
    await expect(tx)
      .to.emit(factory, 'ContractDeployed')
      .withArgs(deployer.address, anticipatedAddress);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- For `python` you can achieve this like this. You will need the `web3.py` or `brownie` & `rlp` modules installed.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from brownie import web3, accounts
import rlp


def get_addr(attacker):
    # Convert from hex to bytes. Be sure to drop the leading 0x
    sender = bytes.fromhex(attacker.address[2:])

    # The nonce is just a number
    nonce = attacker.nonce

    # Last 20 bytes means the last 40 characters in hexadecimal
    contract_address = f"0x{web3.keccak(rlp.encode([sender, nonce])).hex()[-40:]}"

    return contract_address


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_addr(accounts[0]))
```

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcrdn.png)